# Plotting from line to line with gnuplot

Tags: database, csv, plot, gnuplot, txt

I have a .txt file in which two set of data are in the same column but divided by some characters, here an example:

#First set of data
#Time         #Velocity
1                    0.3
2                    0.5
3                    0.8
4                    1.3

#Second set of data
#Time         #Velocity
1                    0.7
2                    0.9
3                    1.8
4                    2.3

So I would like to plot this two set of data as two different curves, and also I do not  know how many lines has each set of data ( or at least this number can change ) so i cannot use every command.( I'm looking for some gnuplot command, not bash command).
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already mentioned `every` will not work here, since you have variable lengths of datasets *(**edit**: yes it will, see edit below)*.
In case you had two empty lines to separate your datasets you could use index, check `help index`.
However, if you have a single empty line, `pseudocolumn -1` will help. Check `help pseudocolumns`.
Then you can define a filter with the ternary operator, check `help ternary`.

**Code:**

```
### plotting variable datasets
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#First set of data
#Time        #Velocity
1              0.3
2              0.5
3              0.8
4              1.3

#Second set of data
#Time        #Velocity
1              0.7
2              0.9
3              1.8

#Third set of data
#Time        #Velocity
1              0.9
2              1.4
3              2.6
4              3.6
5              4.8
EOD

myFilter(col,i) = column(-1)==i-1 ? column(col) : NaN

set key top left
plot for [i=1:3] $Data u 1:(myFilter(2,i)) w lp pt 7 title sprintf("Set %d",i)
### end of code
```

**Edit:** (as @binzo pointed out)

Actually, I made it too complicated. As simple as the following will also do it without filter (filter can be used on other occasions). Note, the blocks are numbered starting from 0.

```
plot for [i=1:3] $Data u 1:2 every :::i-1::i-1 w lp pt 7 title sprintf("Set  %d",i)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You may also want to have a look to the following answers with no separation between blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64423162/7295599 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64482390/7295599

Comment: In the case of using $Data in your example, you could also use 'every' as follows. `plot for [i=0:2] $Data every :::i::i u 1:2 w lp pt 7 title sprintf("Set %d",i+1)`

Comment: @binzo, you're absolutely right... sorry for making things more complicated than they are. The blocks (or sets or whatever you call it) which you can address via `every` are seperated by exactly one empty line as in the OPs question. I will add it.